# Selects tables and translate their content using your own dictionary

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts, dictionary

My word file has a lot of tables and charts. I want to select just the tables and translate them in English and Russian.

The content of the tables are very specific (economic meaning) and I have my own dictionary for translation.

Now, I have to do copy/paste every quarter in order to translate these tables - loose of time! Why copy/paste? Because I have new statistic data in tables and the format of the table is specific, I have to translate just first column (name of indicators) and first range (period, change in share ...). And it is not excluded that in the current quarter will appear new indicators, that means new ranges. This is why I need a link between the words in my mother language and their translation in English and Russian. My own dictionary is in Excel.

I need also a solution for translating the charts, but the situation is more difficult in case of tables.

Comment: I'm not aware of any solution available already. If you really need that, then you need to write macro which loops through all words and replace them from the dictionary.